# Does this system of equations have attractors and periodic solutions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, taylor-expansion, approximation

I want to solve the following exercise:

*Determine the critical points of the system*
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= x^2- y^3\\
\dot{y} &= 2x(x^2 - y)
\end{align}
*Are there attractors in this system? Determine a first integral. Do periodic solutions exist?*

**What I've tried so far:**

I think that I've found the critical points of this system. If I inspect
\begin{align}
x^2 - y^3 = 0\\
2x(x^2 - y) = 0
\end{align}
I find that $x = 0$ or $x = \pm \sqrt{y}$.

Case $x = 0$:

$-y^3 = 0$ so that $y = 0$. Hence the first critical point that I find is $(0,0)$.

Case $x = \pm\sqrt{y}$:

$y - y^3 = 0$ so $y=1$ or $y = -1$. If $y = -1$ then $x = \pm i$. If $y = 1$ then $x = \pm1$. Hence I find the critical points $(1, 1), (i, -1), (-1,1),$ and $(-i,-1)$. I think that I've found a first integral by looking at the equation
$$
\dfrac{\dfrac{dy}{dt}}{\dfrac{dx}{dt}} = \dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{2x^3 - 2xy}{x^2 - y^3}
$$
Integrating this final equation gives 
$$
\int \dfrac{2x^3 - 2xy}{x^2 - y^3}dx = y(y^2 - 1)\log(y^3 - x^2) + x^2 + C
$$
Hence a first integral of this system is
$$
F(x,y) = y(y^2 - 1)\log(y^3 - x^2) + x^2
$$
I tried plotting this function to find out if the system of equations has periodic solutions but I don't get any wiser looking at the plots.

I have the following definitions of an attractor:

*A critical point $x = a$ of the equation $\dot{x} = f(x)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is called a positive attractor if there exists a neighborhood $\Omega_a\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ of $x = a$ such that $x(t_0)\in\Omega_a$ implies $\lim_{t\to\infty} x(t) = a$. If a critical point $x = a$ has this property for $t \to - \infty$ then $x = a$ is called a negative attractor.*

I think that in order to determine whether either of the critical points is an attractor I need to know what the solution $x(t)$ looks like. I'm not sure how to solve this system though and if I enter the equations in wolfram then I don't get a solution either (I might be missing something). So therefore I tried to linearize the equations. I have:
$$
f(x, y) = \begin{pmatrix}x^2 - y^3\\2x(x^2 - y)\end{pmatrix}, \dfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial(x,y)} = \begin{pmatrix}2x & -3y^2\\6x^2& -2x\end{pmatrix}, \dfrac{\partial^2f(x,y)}{\partial (x,y)^2} = \begin{pmatrix}2 & -6y\\12x & 0\end{pmatrix}, \\\dfrac{\partial^3 f(x,y)}{\partial (x,y)^3} = \begin{pmatrix}0 & -6\\12 & 0\end{pmatrix}
$$
Hence, using the Taylor expansion around $(x,y) = (0,0)$ I get
\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= x^2 - y^3 + \ldots\\
\dot{y} &= 2x^3 + \ldots
\end{align}
but I'm not really sure how I can use this to learn anything new..

**Question:** How can I learn more about this system so that I will be able to say more about the existence of attractors and periodic solutions? Is my reasoning thus far correct?

Comment: Your integration for the first integral is not correct, you would need to consider $y$ as a function of $x$, not as a constant.

Comment: The Jacobian is wrong in the lower left entry, you need the $x$ derivative of both terms in $2x^3-2xy$. The higher order derivatives are tensors, as pure tensor the second derivative has 8 entries, as symmetric tensor this reduces to 6 independent entries.

Comment: The Taylor expansion of any polynomial around the origin is that same polynomial again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\dot{x} &= x^2- y^3\\
\dot{y} &= 2x(x^2 - y)
\end{align}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2x(x^2 - y)}{x^2- y^3}$$
Let $X=x^2$
$$\frac{dy}{dX}=\frac{X - y}{X- y^3}$$
$$\frac{dX}{dy}=\frac{X- y^3}{X-y}$$
Let $X=y+u$
$$\frac{dX}{dy}=1+\frac{du}{dy}=\frac{y+u- y^3}{u}$$
$$\frac{du}{dy}=\frac{y- y^3}{u}$$
$$2udu=2(y-y^3)dy$$
$$u^2=y^2-\frac12 y^4+c$$
$$(X-y)^2=(x^2-y)^2=y^2-\frac12 y^4+c$$
$$x^4-2x^2y=-\frac12 y^4+c$$
The equation of the trajectory is :
$$\boxed{y^4-4x^2y+2x^4=2c}$$
The analytical study of this  equation shows that $c\geq -\frac12$ and that the trajectory is a closed curve.

[image]

Comment: +1, I adore when someone sees all these changes of variables that lead to a final solution, but one observation just for the sake of simplification. The original system can be rewritten as an equivalent first order equation $\lbrack 2x^3 - 2xy \rbrack \, dx + \lbrack y^3 - x^2 \rbrack \, dy = 0$. This equation happens to be exact and thus system has a first integral $\Phi(x, y) = \frac{x^4}{2} - x^2y + \frac{y^4}{4}$, which is exactly the same that you've found.